# Ellipse tangent line intersection with lines $y=c$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I am writing an image processing algorithm, and in the process am stuck on a geometry/algebra question.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vPPbZDR.png]

I have an axis-aligned ellipse at the origin, with axes $a$ and $b$. Parallel to the major axis, there are two line segments with lengths $D_1$ and $D_2$. The line connecting the ends of the line segments is a tangent to the ellipse, it touches but does not intersect the ellipse.

The question is: given $a$, $b$ and the ratio $F = {D_1\over D_2}$, how to calculate the lengths of $D_1$ and $D_2$?

Some notes on current progress:

- I believe the solution exists and is uniquely defined. Every $F$ ratio defines a set of lines, but only one of these lines touches the ellipse.
- The $F$ ratio on its own does not determine the angle between the tangent line and the $x$ axis. $D_1=2$, $D_2=1$ has a different angle than $D_1=20$, $D_2=10$.
- If it is useful, can make assumptions like $b=1$ and $a > b$ and $D_1 > D_2$, since these do not lose generality and I can translate it to an arbitrary ellipse and $F$ ratio afterwards.

Comment: Not sure about note 2 ... .

Comment: Diagram about note 2: http://i.imgur.com/yTLUdH8.png

With a constant `F` ratio, the angle changes as `D1` and `D2` increase.

Comment: I am getting $D_1=a\sqrt{F}$ and $D_2=a\left/\sqrt{F}\right.$

Comment: Are the two segments tangent to the ellipse, as drawn, or at an arbitrary distance from the $x$-axis, as in your title?

Comment: Yes, the two lines with lengths D1 and D2 are tangents to the ellipse as well, parallel to the x axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to tackle this. One way is to observe that the family of lines with ratio $F$ has a common intersection at $\left(0,{F+1\over F-1}b\right)$, so this problem reduces to finding the tangents to the ellipse through this point.

A direct computation using a generic tangent to the ellipse isn’t a particularly difficult way to go here, either. An equation of the tangent to the ellipse at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $b^2x_0(x-x_0)+a^2y_0(y-y_0)=0$. Using the parameterization $(x_0,y_0)=(a\cos t,b\sin t)$ for the ellipse and solving for $x$ at $y=\pm b$ gives $$\begin{align}D_1&=a(\cos t+\tan t+\sin t\tan t)\\D_2&=a(\cos t-\tan t+\sin t\tan t).\end{align}$$ From this we get $D_1D_2=a^2$ which, combined with $F=D_1/D_2$, yields $D_1=a\sqrt F$, $D_2=a/\sqrt F$ just as in Lozenges’ comment.

Comment: Thank you! Surprising at first that `b` is eliminated from the solution.

Comment: @user2815082 That was indeed a pleasant surprise. It turns out that the x-coordinate of the point of tangency for the line through the common intersection of the $F$-line family is independent of $b$ and the $y$-coordinate is directly proportional to $b$. This makes the $x$-intercept of the tangent line independent of $b$, too, which makes the intersections of the tangent line with any horizontal line independent of $b$. I’m sure that there must be some nice geometric explanation for this.

Comment: @user2815082 Turns out that there is a fairly nice geometric solution to this that also explains why the lengths are independent of $b$. If I have time, I’ll post it. The basic approach is to start by examining a tangent to a circle and its intersections with the other two parallel tangent lines, and then stretching it.

Comment: @amd ($x$-coordinate of the point of tangency) * ($x$-intercept of the tangent line) $=a^2$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, examine the unit circle:

[image]

A bit of angle chasing determines that that $\angle{OAA'}=\angle{COC'}$, so that $CC':OC'::OA':AA'$. But $D_1=AA'$ and $D_2=CC'$, so $D_1D_2=1$. Combined with $D_1/D_2=F$ this gives $D_1=\sqrt F$ and $D_2=1/\sqrt F$.

To generalize to an ellipse, recall that affine transformations preserve intersections of lines and segment proportions along parallel lines, as well as points of tangency. A vertical change of scale maintains the above proportions and doesn’t change the horizontal spacing of any of these points, so the segment lengths $D_1$ and $D_2$ are independent of the vertical axis length. A horizontal change of scale by a factor of $a$, on the other hand, also preserves the ratio of $D_1$ to $D_2$, but multiplies each segment length by $a$. Therefore, for an ellipse in standard position, $D_1=a\sqrt F$ and $D_2=a/\sqrt F$, as was computed analytically.